# Speaker adaptation of acoustic model for Indian accent kaldi ASR

Tags: neural-network, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am working on getting speech recognition for Indian accent speakers. Presently, I am using the online nnet2 decoding tool of Kaldi ASR.
The tool is working well when the speaker has good english pronunciation. But, it is failing when the speaker speaks in a accent different from the US english accent.

So, can anyone please suggest any procedure for speaker adaptation of acoustic or neural network model using Kaldi ASR?

Comment: By *slang* do you mean *accent*?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how you can do it or think about that.

1 - If you are talking only about accent (this means, no new words, standard grammar) -> Then you should mainly work with acoustic part of model. Get as much of audio & transcription data as you can (hundreds of hours) so you can update the H-part of model.

2 - If you are talking about something more complex, you should think about updating the lexicon (add word) & grammar (fst's) too (including my first point).

You can try to start with AMI model and its papers, that is included in examples in Kaldi. See [Examples included with Kaldi](http://kaldi-asr.org/doc/examples.html)